# angularjs link function not beeing executed when controller is present

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a little confused right now. I wrote a directive, which basically opens different modals depending on some "status".
For some reason the "link" function is no longer executed, it did a while back. I have no idea when it stopped working. Maybe some poorly resolved merge conflicts, maybe some angular minor update?
Hope anyone can help oder hint me in the right direction.

link function is called wheren no controller is present, otherwise it's not executed. Commenting out the logic of the controller will also not result in the execution of link.

```
<hcd-modal-messages status="status" redirect="app.dashboard.index"></hcd-modal-messages>
```

directive:

```
angular
    .module('hcdProtocol')
    .directive('hcdModalMessages', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'app/protocols/components/modalMessages/modalMessages.html',
            scope: {
                labelSuccess: '@labelSuccess',
                labelProcess: '@labelProcess',
                labelFailed: '@labelFailed',
                labelCached: '@labelCached',
                status: '=status', //values: HIDDEN, PROCESS, SUCCESS, FAIL
                redirect: '=redirect',
                delay: '@redirectDelay' //delay in milliseconds
            },
            controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', '$state', function($scope, $timeout, $state) {
            $scope.processModal = new Foundation.Reveal(
                angular.element(angular.element(".modal-process")[0]),
                {
                    closeOnClick: false
                }
            );
            $scope.successModal = new Foundation.Reveal(
                angular.element(angular.element(".modal-success")[0]),
                {
                    closeOnClick: false
                }
            );
            $scope.failModal = new Foundation.Reveal(
                angular.element(angular.element(".modal-fail")[0]),
                {
                    closeOnClick: true
                }
            );
            $scope.offlineModal = new Foundation.Reveal(
                angular.element(angular.element(".modal-cached")[0]),
                {
                    closeOnClick: false
                }
            );

            $scope.$watch('status', function(status) {
                //close all modals
                $scope.processModal.close();
                $scope.successModal.close();
                $scope.failModal.close();
                //open modal corresponding to current status
                switch(status) {
                    case 'PROCESS':
                        $scope.processModal.open();
                        break;
                    case 'SUCCESS':
                        $scope.successModal.open();

                        if(typeof $scope.redirect !== 'undefined') {
                            //delay redirection
                            $timeout(function () {
                                $state.go($scope.redirect);
                            }, $scope.redirectDelay);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'OFFLINE_CACHED':
                        $scope.offlineModal.open();

                        if(typeof $scope.redirect !== 'undefined') {
                            //delay redirection
                            $timeout(function () {
                                $state.go($scope.redirect);
                            }, $scope.redirectDelay);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'FAIL':
                        $scope.failModal.open();
                        break;
                }
            });

            }],
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
                //set default label
                if(typeof attrs.labelProcess == 'undefined') scope.labelProcess = "Creating new protocol";
                if(typeof attrs.labelSuccess  == 'undefined') scope.labelSuccess = "successfully created";
                if(typeof attrs.labelFailed  == 'undefined') scope.labelFailed = "creation failed";
                if(typeof attrs.labelCached  == 'undefined') scope.labelCached = "Created in offline cache";

                scope.redirectDelay = (typeof attrs['redirect-delay']  === 'undefined') ? 3000 : attrs['redirect-delay'];
                scope.redirect = (typeof attrs.redirect === 'undefined') ? false : attrs.redirect;

                //close modals when directive ist destroy to avoid grey (ui blocking) overlay
                scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    scope.processModal.close();
                    scope.failModal.close();
                    scope.successModal.close();
                    scope.offlineModal.close();
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm currently using AngularJS v1.5.3

*My Quick fix:* I ended up putting the controller logic into my link function. Most of it belonged there in the first place. so its working now since I don't have a controller, but I still don't unterstand why controller and link were not executed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use this format

```
angular
    .module('module')
    .controller('MyCtrl',/*your controller*/)
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            require: '^^MyCtrl',
            link: function (scope, el, attrs, MyCtrl) /*....*/
        }
    })
```

Comment: this leads to "Controller 'hcdModalMessagesController', required by directive 'hcdModalMessages', can't be found!"